# Racket -UpperCase

Tags: scheme, racket

```
; defining the procedure char_toupper to convert a lower case character to upper case
(define char_toupper (lambda (myChar)
                       ; defining x as the ASCII value of myChar
                       (define x (char->integer myChar))
                       ; defining y as x-32
                       (define y (- x 32))
                       ; if statement for while x is less than 91 (already uppercase)
                       (if (< x 91)
                            ; if it is already uppercase, just display it
                            (display myChar)
                            ; otherwise, if x is greater than 96 (lowercase)
                            (if (> x 96)
                                ; then display the character equivalent to the ASCII value given by y
                                (display (integer->char y))))))

(define string_toupper (lambda (myString newString i)       
                         (if (< i (string-length myString))
                             (string_toupper myString (string-append newString (char_toupper (string-ref myString i))) (+ 1 i)))

                         (display newString)))
(string_toupper (read) "" 0)
```

This converts each character to upper case, and displays it. But I keep getting an error and I can find it. Any help. Thanks

Comment: And the error you keep getting is?

Comment: string-length: contract violation
  expected: string?

Comment: read does not necessarily return strings.  It returns a value back, but that value might be a string, or a symbol, or a number, or a list, or... depending on what the user typed in.  So you probably want to use read-line instead:  http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Byte_and_String_Input.html#(def._((quote._~23~25kernel)._read-line))

Comment: Also char_toupper function actually returns void...

Answer (score 2):

In Racket you must write `when` instead of `if` in the one-armed case.

That is, change the `if` in the following expression to `when`.

```
(if (> x 96)
    ; then display the character equivalent to the ASCII value given by y
    (display (integer->char y)))
```

Also note that [string-upcase](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/strings.html?q=upcase#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._string-upcase%29%29) is builtin.

Comment: Similarly, char-upcase is also built in: http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/characters.html#(def._((quote._~23~25kernel)._char-upcase))